# How to merge DataFrames on their columns index places?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes (note column indices):

[image] = A =

```
        2   3   4
    0   A1  A1  A1
    1   A2  A2  A2
    2   A3  A3  A3
    3   A4  A4  A4
    4   A5  A5  A5
```

[image] = B =

```
    6   7   8   9
0   B1  B1  B1  B1
1   B2  B2  B2  B2
2   B3  B3  B3  B3
3   B4  B4  B4  B4
4   B5  B5  B5  B5
```

I want to merge them into dataframe, where they will be at their index places, and the rest filled with nothing, for example:

[image]

What is the best (pythonic) way to do it?

Those dataframes were generated with the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(10))
A = ['A' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]
B = ['B' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]
df[[2,3,4]] = list(zip(A, A, A))
df[[6,7,8,9]] = list(zip(B, B, B, B))
df.fillna('', inplace = True)   # Output dataframe
df.drop(columns = [0, 1] + list(range(5, 10)))   # A dataframe
df.drop(columns = list(range(0, 6)))    # B dataframe
```

**UPD** I thank all contributors, that was very insightful. `reindex` seems to be the most elegant way to do it. However, constantstranger in the end provided the most thoughtful update, and also showed convenient way to store smaller DataFrame inside non-empty large dataframe, according to its columns indexes, which is also valuable for me. So, however difficult it was to choose best answer, I pick his.

For whoever will struggle with the similar task, I might add, that `fill_value = ''` during reindex will help to get rid of pesky NaNs.

Comment: Kindly use text, instead of images. Helps to copy paste and respond fast. Thanks

Comment: have a look here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: @quest
Thank you for your suggestion, I thought generation code would be enough. Added text variants as well.

Comment: you can use pd.concat and also considering the ignore_index in concat.

Comment: @grumpyp, Sadow,
I did read the docs, but still can't wrap my head around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you've asked:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.DataFrame(data={j: ['A' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)] for j in range(2, 5)})
B = pd.DataFrame(data={j: ['B' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)] for j in range(6, 10)})
print(A)
print(B)

newColumns = range(1 + max(A.columns[-1], B.columns[-1]))
df = pd.DataFrame({newCol: [np.nan] * max(len(A.index), len(B.index)) for newCol in newColumns})
df[A.columns] = A
df[B.columns] = B
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    2   3   4
0  A1  A1  A1
1  A2  A2  A2
2  A3  A3  A3
3  A4  A4  A4
4  A5  A5  A5
    6   7   8   9
0  B1  B1  B1  B1
1  B2  B2  B2  B2
2  B3  B3  B3  B3
3  B4  B4  B4  B4
4  B5  B5  B5  B5
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0 NaN NaN  A1  A1  A1 NaN  B1  B1  B1  B1
1 NaN NaN  A2  A2  A2 NaN  B2  B2  B2  B2
2 NaN NaN  A3  A3  A3 NaN  B3  B3  B3  B3
3 NaN NaN  A4  A4  A4 NaN  B4  B4  B4  B4
4 NaN NaN  A5  A5  A5 NaN  B5  B5  B5  B5
```

If you prefer a fill value other than NaN (such as the empty string), you can change this in the initialization of df.

**UPDATE:**

An alternative to the `= A` and `= B` lines above is this:

```py
df[list(A.columns) + list(B.columns)] = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Ohter answers (by @mozway and @Shubham Sharma) have suggested using `reindex()`, which is elegant. I would just note that to be more generic, reindex should probably use the max column label of A and B (rather than relying on one being the larger):

```py
df = pd.concat([A, B], axis = 1).reindex(range(max(A.columns[-1], B.columns[-1]) + 1), axis = 'columns')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Whatever the best answer would be, that was very educational for me. Like your one-liners for A and B generation, and A.columns[-1] to find max index approach!

And your update is eye-opening for me, as well.

Comment: Glad this helped. The reindex() approach suggested in other answers is a good one. I have updated my answer with a variation that doesn't rely on B having a larger max column label than A.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do `reindex` after `join`

```
C = A.join(B)
C = C.reindex(range(C.columns.max() + 1), axis=1)
```

---

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0 NaN NaN  A1  A1  A1 NaN  B1  B1  B1  B1
1 NaN NaN  A2  A2  A2 NaN  B2  B2  B2  B2
2 NaN NaN  A3  A3  A3 NaN  B3  B3  B3  B3
3 NaN NaN  A4  A4  A4 NaN  B4  B4  B4  B4
4 NaN NaN  A5  A5  A5 NaN  B5  B5  B5  B5
```

Comment: We had almost the same approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can `concat` and `reindex`:

```
out = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1).reindex(columns=range(B.columns.max()+1))
```

or, if you don't know in which input lies the max columns (python ≥ 3.8):

```
out = (d:=pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)).reindex(columns=range(d.columns.max()+1))
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0 NaN NaN  A1  A1  A1 NaN  B1  B1  B1  B1
1 NaN NaN  A2  A2  A2 NaN  B2  B2  B2  B2
2 NaN NaN  A3  A3  A3 NaN  B3  B3  B3  B3
3 NaN NaN  A4  A4  A4 NaN  B4  B4  B4  B4
4 NaN NaN  A5  A5  A5 NaN  B5  B5  B5  B5
```